# Portfolio optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, finance

Mathematica provides codes for a portfolio optimization https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/summerschool/pages/2017/AndresLopezMartinez_TE that do not work anymore.

Any reason why?

I have been trying to combine several codes together, but I have been unsuccessful doing it.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because of this:

```
getReturns[lst_] := (lst[[# + 1]]/lst[[#]]) - 1 & /@ Range[Length[lst] - 1];
```

`FinancialData` returns a `TimeSeries`. The `Range[Length[lst] - 1]` goes from $0$ to $n-1$ so the zeroth element, which is the head `TimeSeries` ends up in the calculation of the means.

If you look at the documentation for [`FinancialData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html), you can get returns directly without needing to calculate them: there's a `"Return"` property.

You could also rectify this by adding "Values" like this:

```
data = FinancialData[#, "Close", {2010, 1, 1}, "Value"]["Values"] & /@ portfolio;
```

Later on you'll have problems transposing the returns matrix in the covariance calculation because the length of the returns data doesn't produce a square matrix. Have a look at `Length /@ returns`.